# Tener una web en varios Idomas

Tags: html

Buenas tardes,

Me gustaría que mi página web se pueda traducir a varios idiomas. Me gustaría poner en el header de mi web las típicas banderas de idiomas donde al hacer click en ellas la pagina se traduce al idioma seleccionado.

¿Cómo lo podría realizar?

Muchas gracias por las sugerencias,

Comment: Si no estás usando programación en el servidor, puedes incorporar el plugin de google para traducciones de sitios. Es rápido y funciona en la mayoría de casos.

Comment: Simple, traduce el sitio contratando personas. No uses traductores automáticos y lo de la bandera es un detalle final. El costo es traducir, adapatar y reacomodar cosas que quedan mal ubicadas.

Comment: @md: Por experiencia: no siempre es tan simple. Las traducciones hechas por personas contratadas no suelen tener en cuenta los contextos culturales. Yo digo "coger un coche", pero este texto en Argentina quizá no es lo más adecuado.

Comment: @gontrollez es muy cierto lo que dices. He ayudado con la traducción de este sitio y se que algunas cadenas requirieron de personas que conozcan bien el contexto para una adecuada traducción, pero no son tantas, tal vez el 1% o menos. Pero considera esto, se contrato gente para hacer la traducción; por que no puedes usar traductores automáticos... (por suerte, si así fuera este sitio no existiria).

Answer (score 2):

Si lo estas haciendo con php, deberias tener un archivo con todos los textos en los idiomas que quieres y cuando haces click en la bandera pasar por get una variable, que puede ser 'eng' o 'es' por ejemplo y detectar por php que si es una u otra utilizar un archivo de idiomas u otro.

Si lo estas haciendo solo con html puedes hacer la misma página en tantos idiomas como quieras poner.

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos opciones para poder hacerlo.
1.- Es la mas costosa de mantener, ya que requiere hacer las páginas como si fuesen estáticas, y cada cambio, lo tendrías que hacer en todos los lenguajes. Esta opción no te la recomiendo.

2.- Si trabajas con bases de datos, guardar los textos en los idiomas que quieras y cargar los textos en función del lenguaje seleccionado. Ademas puedes guardar el idioma en una cookie, y así si el visitante vuelve a visitar tu sitio, ya sabes el idioma a mostrar la web.